# How to create @ManyToMany mapping wiht hibernate not on primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two tables:

- `User (ID, name)` where name is a unique row and `ID` is the PK
- `Role (ID, name)` where `ID` is the PK

Now I know I can connect these using JPA

**In my User:**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "UserHasRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private List<RoleEntity> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

**And on RoleEntity-side:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

It works fine so far, but I'd like to use `UserEntity`'s `name` instead of `id` in the `@ManyToMany`-relationship. How can I do that?

My column definitions in `UserEntity`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;
```

Comment: Might this link help you https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @GovindParashar this goes into a different direction. It's about how to assign extra columns to a `@ManyToMany` relationship, but I want to use the `@ManyToMany` with a column different than the Primary Key and not use the PK.